# Poor intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 for C++ Win32

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, documentation, intellisense

For a long time i was programming in Visual Studio 2010 in C#. Really good thing there was extensive documentation in Lntellisense. Lately i have decided to switch to C++ Win32 (which i believe is Native C++, am I right?). I have then spotted Intellisense is only showing functions' declarations (with no descriptions and with no parameter descriptions). It really makes programming hard as it is hard for me to remember all of the functions' parameters.

So the is: is there any way to make Intellisense to show documentation and parameter list descriptions for C++ win32 just like it was in C#?

If there is no such way, so is there way to provide my own XML documentation for existing win32 functions for C++? I could then write documentation for my most used functions for myself, which would be really helpful.

I have also noticed typing three slashes before function declaration does nothing (in C# it was used to write XML documentation for specified objecT). Is there any way to bring back such functionality?

Comment: Yup.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177226%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

But it doesn't hide the tags.

Oh, and with visual studio 2010, there is no intelesence for C++/CLI. Google it!

Comment: So is C++ Win32 the same as C++/CLI? I have googled it couple times but i could not find any clarification on about what is C++/CLI.

Comment: C++ Win32 is C++ with the windows libraries, C++/CLI is the visual studio managed C++ (But is not, in any way, C++ but rather a different language entirely)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) for better intellisense. It's a commercial tool (I'm not affiliated with them but I've been using it for a while). It provides features for most of the things you asked for through enhanced intellisense and macros / shortcuts.

For the most part I like it but there are some annoying issues with it that I had to learn to live with. Support is all right but every once in a while they break something that used to work before.

Comment: I have heard about Visual Assist X. So it does have ready documentation for C++, and isn't only a tool which i can use to write my own documentation?

Comment: It doesn't have any specific documentation for any language but it parses all C / C++ and header files in your project and shows whatever information is available from those. If functions have comments, they'll be shown and function parameters, enums, etc. are also showm. If somethins is undocumented, it'll still show parameter types / names but nothing more. It works for C# and VB.Net, too.

Comment: You can also define various shortcuts that - when you type them - expand into various code blocks. It's a fairly fast way to create common code blocks (faster than picking items from the snippet menu).

Comment: Thank you very much. Apparently it was what i was looking for.

Comment: By the way - I have additional question. Why Microsoft didn't provide any documentation for C++ just like for C#?

Comment: @Rob Probably because in C#, XML documentation can be generated more easily. Be aware that you may not see comments in VA if the various headers / source files don't have comments. You'll see tooltips with parameter types / names but no explanation. If you update the headers with comments, they'll be shown, just like comments from your own code.